# how to create console command in a module?

Tags: yii2

`console command`, like `./yii hello/world`.

I'm using `yii-app-basic`.

what I want is not create console command in the dir `commands/` but in a `module`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) Your module should implements BootstrapInterface** :

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module implements \yii\base\BootstrapInterface
{

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        if ($app instanceof \yii\console\Application) {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\my_module\commands';
        }
    }

}
```

**2) Create your console controller in your module `commands` folder** :

```
namespace app\modules\my_module\commands;

class ConsoleController extends \yii\console\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "Hello World\n";
    }
}
```

**3) Add your module to your app console configuration `config/console.php`** :

```
'bootstrap' => [
    // ... other bootstrap components ...
    'my_module',
],
'modules' => [
    // ... other modules ...
    'my_module' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\my_module\Module',
    ],
],
```

**4) You can now use your command** :

```
yii my_module/console/index
```

Comment: What if I want my module commands to have the following format: `yii my_module/command` (without the controller name)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good [Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/820/yii2-create-console-commands-inside-a-module-or-extension/) and [Discussion](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/66756-how-make-a-console-command-in-a-new-module/).

**Follow Below Steps on Tutorial:**

```
1) Create a new module in your application. 
2) Edit the Module.php. 
3) Create your folder and command inside your module. 
4) Add your module to app configurations.
```

Comment: I tried it with extension but id didn't work. Any idea why?