# Yii2: How to create module commands without controller name?

Tags: yii2, yii2-extension, yii2-module

There was a similar question asking "[how to create console command in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711006/how-to-create-console-command-in-a-module)" which contains a good answer on how to add commands to your Yii2 modules.

However, the resulting commands must be in the following format:

`./yii module_name/command/sub-command`

where `command` corresponds with the console Controller name, and `sub-command` corresponds with its Action names.

How do we omit the controller name and have it list action names only so that our commands will be in the following format:

`./yii module_name/command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of dividing console commands to modules, and hiding controller name (like making it a DefaultController).

But anyway, one of the possible solutions is to configure `controllerMap` in `config\console.php` file (considering you are using a basic template).

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    ...
    'controllerMap' => [
        'module_name' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\module_name\commands\ConsoleController',
        ],
    ],
    ...
];
```

So now when you run `php yii module_name/<action_name>`, it calls directly `ConsoleController` actions

..so i.e. `php yii module_name/index` results to `module_name\ConsoleController->actionIndex()` method

Comment: Seems like this is pretty much the *only* solution.